# JQuery Dialog doesn't work

Tags: jquery

It's for 3 hours i try to work a JQuery Dialog.
My code is this and it is very simple:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#finestra').dialog();
    });
</script>

<div>

    <p>
        JQuery Dialog Test
    </p>

    <div id="finestra" title="Test">
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
```

JQuery works: if i write for example     $('#finestra').css('color','blue');   this works.

Whats is the problem? :(

Comment: You have not loaded jQuery UI script

Comment: Make sure you have the src `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. Works after including ui. http://jsfiddle.net/n60z5j1m/

Comment: Guys is the first row!!!   do you read  my post or not? :P

Comment: @ZorZy, You are not reading correctly __jquery-ui.js__ apart from that there is no issue.

Comment: @Satpal if i don't read correctly jquery why: " $('#finestra').css('color','blue');" works?

Comment: @ZorZy, [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is part of jQuery library (which you have loaded hence works) and [`.dialog();`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) is part of jQuery UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not loaded jQuery UI library. You need to simply add the relevant library and its CSS file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#finestra').dialog();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    JQuery Dialog Test
  </p>
  <div id="finestra" title="Test">
    <div>content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```